Route 53 to ALB connection giving 502 bad gateway
I am setting up domain configuration using Amazon Route 53 but when I hit domain url it's giving 502 bad gateway in browser, However my ALB url is working fine and target group is healthy.
Below are the steps I performed:
I have created ALB in AWS that accepts incoming traffic on port 443 and added ACM certificates in ALB.
ACM certificate contains below domains. The domain "fivapps.net" is purchased in Route 53 only.

fivapps.net
*.fivapps.net

Now in Route 53, I created A record that points to ALB url and CNAME records as per below.



Record name
Type
Routing policy
Alias
Value/Route traffic to
TTL




jfrog.fivapps.net
A
Simple
yes
{ALB url that is working}
60


_c56b3f11f6fb8.fivapps.net
CNAME
Simple
No
_cff83caf43fc9ea3746
60



After that when I try https://jfrog.fivapps.net it's giving me 502 bad gateway error on internet.
I did perform steps as per  AWS documentation and also checked several resources but could not resolve this issue.

It seems issue was with my ALB only. Route 53 configuration was correct.
I deleted listener from ALB and re-created target group that solved my issue.
